# Type mismatch in async method

Tags: asynchronous, types, f#, timeout, matching

I have an asynchronous method I'm writing which is supposed to asynchronously query for a port until it finds one, or time out at 5 minutes;

```ml
    member this.GetPort(): Async<Port> = this._GetPort(DateTime.Now)

    member this._GetPort(startTime: DateTime): Async<Port> = async {
        match this._TryGetOpenPort() with
        | Some(port) -> port
        | None -> do
            if (DateTime.Now - startTime).TotalMinutes >= 5 then
                raise (Exception "Unable to open a port")
            else
                do! Async.Sleep(100)
                let! result = this._GetPort(startTime)
                result}

    member this._TryGetOpenPort(): Option<Port> = 
        // etc.
```

However, I'm getting some strange type inconsistencies in `_GetPort`; the function says I'm returning a type of `Async<unit>` instead of `Async<Port>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a little unintuitive, but way to make your code work would be this:

```
member private this.GetPort(startTime: DateTime) =
    async {
        match this.TryGetOpenPort() with
        | Some port ->
            return port
        | None ->
            if (DateTime.Now - startTime).TotalMinutes >= 5 then
                raise (Exception "Unable to open a port")
            
            do! Async.Sleep(100)
            let! result = this.GetPort(startTime)
            return result
    }

member private this.TryGetOpenPort() = failwith "yeet" // TODO
```

I took the liberty to clean up a few things and make the member private, since that seems to be what you're largely going after here with a more detailed internal way to get the port.

The reason why your code wasn't compiling was because you were inconsistent in what you were `return`ing from the computation:

- In the case of `Some(port)` you were missing a `return` keyword - which is required to lift the value back into an `Async<port>`
- Your `if` expression where you raise an exception had an `else` branch but you weren't `return`ing from both. In this case, since you clearly don't wish to return anything and just raise an exception, you can omit the `else` and make it an imperative program flow just like in non-async code.

The other thing you may wish to consider down the road is if throwing an exception is what you want, or if just returning a `Result<T,Err>` or an option is the right call. Exceptions aren't inherently bad, but often a lot of F# programming leads to avoiding their use if there's a good way to ascribe meaning to a type that wraps your return value.

Comment: Thanks, i'm new to F#. I didn't realize that `return` was required within `async` blocks, since it's not in other blocks.

Comment: The material is a little dense (I wrote it, heh, sorry), but I recommend keeping this reference open: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/tutorials/asynchronous-and-concurrent-programming/async

And ScottW's seminal work is a great place to go too: https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/concurrency-async-and-parallel//

After it simmers in your brain a little it makes more sense!